# NULL Value Handling for CSV Files Via External Tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the NULL_IF parameter of a file format working when applied to an external table.

I have a source CSV file containing NULL values in some columns. NULLS in the source file appear in the format `"\N"` (all non numeric values in the file are quoted). Here is an example line from the raw csv where the ModifiedOn value is NULL in the source system:

```
"AirportId" , "IATACode" , "CreatedOn"           , "ModifiedOn"
1           , "ACU"      , "2015-08-25 16:58:45" , "\N"
```

I have a file format defined including the parameter `NULL_IF = "\\N"`

The following select statement successfully interprets the correct rows as holding NULL values.

```
SELECT $8
FROM @MyS3Bucket 
(
file_format => 'CSV_1', 
pattern => '.*MyFileType.*.csv.gz'
)
```

However if I use the same file format with an external table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE MyTable
MyColumn varchar as (value:c8::varchar)
WITH LOCATION = @MyS3Bucket
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = 'CSV_1')
PATTERN = '.*MyFileType_.*.csv.gz';
```

Each row holds `\N` as a value rather than NULL.

I assume this is caused by external tables providing a single variant output that can then be further split rather than directly presenting individual columns in the csv file.

One solution is to code the NULL handling into the external view like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE MyTable
MyColumn varchar as (NULLIF(value:c8::varchar,'\\N'))
WITH LOCATION = @MyS3Bucket
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = 'CSV_1')
PATTERN = '.*MyFileType_.*.csv.gz';
```

However this leaves me at risk of having to re-write a lot of external table code if the file format changes whereas the file format could\should centralise that NULL definition. It would also mean the NULL conversion would have to be handled column by column rather than file by file increasing code complexity.

Is there a way that I can have the NULL values appear through an external table without handling them explicitly through column definitions?

Ideally this would be applied through a file format object but changes to the format of the raw file are not impossible.

Comment: In the file format you have a "null string" setting, which is \\N by default. Do you get the same behavior if you changed this to "NULL" in the dropdown?

Comment: We've set the format of the CSV itself to record nulls as \N so it matches the Snowflake default. It works for select and copy into just not on an external table. I'll edit to give a clearer example of the current source.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: It's been a long while since I worked with Snowflake. I did report the issue as a bug at the time and had assumed it would get fixed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the issue, and it seems like a bug. If you have access to Snowflake support, it could be better to submit a support case regarding to this issue, so you can easily follow the process.